# SettingWithCopyWarning for pd.to_numeric() column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a column to a numeric integer as follows:

```
def df_column_to_integer(df_column):
    return pd.to_numeric(df_column, errors='coerce', downcast='signed').fillna(0).astype('int64')
```

I use it as follows:

```
df['Column_To_Convert'] = df_column_to_integer(df['Column_To_Convert'])
```

However, this throws a `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

How can I avoid this warning, what is wrong with the code?

Comment: is df from subset ? if so you should adding .copy()

Comment: How do you mean? Add where?

Comment: Just yesterday I've read this article - https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/ - that explains the error very incely. tl;dr, .copy() will help.

Comment: How did you create `df`?

Comment: It is an input to a function, and before that its an input to another function etc. At the root it is loaded in as a .csv

Comment: There must be someplace where you do, for example, `df = other_df.loc[some_mask]`. That's where the problem comes from.

Comment: Why does it not point then where that happens, and not where it does happen?